# Web Cam and Sound drivers for Sony Vaio VGN-SZ48GN

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I installed the W7 RC, everything works very well, except for the cam, mic and speakers. There is nothing to be found on sony's websies, all of them;
If anyone managed to resolve this issue I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you mean, there are no Windows 7 drivers for them?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest downloading the drivers yourself directly from the Sony website.
Win7 downloaded the wrong drivers for my webcam.
If there are no Win7 drivers, try the Vista drivers.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.sony-asia.com/support/download/product/vgn-sz48gn/modelfirst) are all the drivers and software updates that exist for this model; it's straight from the Sony Asia-Pacific product webpage. That's probably the best place to look.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, most of the vista drivers will work for windows 7, however sony has said on their support site that they will be forthcomming with windows 7 drivers nearer or after release to retail. So long as your laptop is ~2 years old or newer then i would have thought they will develop drivers